# How to i select div id onClick event in iframe?

Tags: jquery, iframe

This is my code. I am trying to load a website in a iframe. When the website is loaded, i would like to click in the iframe to select the div id (where i clicked)

```
 <iframe name="frameID" id="frameID" src="http://www.test.com" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></iframe>

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#frameID').load(function(){


    $('#frameID').contents().bind("click", function () {
        var a = $(this).id;
        alert (a);
        return false;
    });
});
```

});

For example, if i clicked in the footer of the website loaded in the iframe, i would like to display the div id "footer".

However, i am unable to do so, it keep returning me undefined.

Comment: If the iframe is in a different domain, you cannot do this.

Comment: Hi, sorry, i didnt make myself clear in the question. http://www.test.com is just an example. exact url should be http://www.mysite.com/test.php -> i used file get contents in php and echo the result in one of my php file (test.php) - its on same domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try

```
$('#frameID').contents().find('body').on("click", "div",  function () {
    var a = this.id;
    alert (a);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: @DerekAng this works only if both iframes are on the same domain

Comment: hi, they are in same domain. http://www.mysite.com/index.php contains the iframe. http://www.mysite.com/test.php is where i file get contents of the url and echoed into.

Comment: @DerekAng one othe thing, this only work with jQuery 1.7 onwards and when you click on a div, do you need it to work when you click anything?

Comment: thanks i updated to 1.7 and it works! why is it so? yea, i need it to work.

Comment: @DerekAng because the method on() has been introduced in 1.7 :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't access to cross domain's document object inside an iframe. Even if it works on your local, it won't be working on a website.

Comment: Hi, sorry, i am new to jquery, what do you mean by cross domain object from inside an iframe?

Comment: You are trying to load a website which your code doesn't work on it. Thus, you can't access the objects inside that iframe due to browser side restrictions.

Comment: Hi, i used php to get file contents of the page and output it in one of my php file.

exact url should be http://www.mysite.com/test.php